# Change the numeric format into 'AM/PM' format in CONCAT / MAX (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to change the numeric format into 'AM/PM' format in CONCAT function (I use SSMS v 18.5.1)

Here is my formula. RCLDTE - is a date and RCLTIM is time. I basically need to leave RCLDTE as it is and change the format of RCLTIM from numeric to date and convert to AM/PM format.

[image: Format that I need]

How the column looks right now

[image: How column looks right now]

Format of RCLTIM - numeric
[image: format]

```
CONCAT(c.RCLDTE, ' & ', MAX(c.RCLTIM)) AS 'Date & Time',
```

When I tried to use CONVERT function as I tend to use, it raised an error.

```
CONCAT(c.RCLDTE, ' & ', CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST( MAX(c.RCLTIM) AS TIME),100))
```

Error

> Explicit conversion from data type numeric to time is not allowed.

Comment: Please don't post images of data; text is text, post it as `text`.

Comment: Of course, the real problem here is your design, don't store formatted data in your RDBMS at all There are 6 [Date and Time Datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes) to choose from and all 6 are **infinitely** better data type choices for a date and time value.

Comment: `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` is your friend here -- convert `RCLDTE` and `RCLTIM` to strings and slice them up. I would strongly recommend that once you *have* a `DATETIME`, though, you *keep* it that way, and leave further formatting to the client.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am not a 100% sure I understand what I need to do. Do you want me to take the whole formula inside DATETIMEFROMPARTS ?

Comment: Side note, telling us the version of SSMS you're using doesn't tell us anything useful. SSMS 18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019 (that's 6.5 different versions). Tell us the version of SQL Server you're using, not the IDE-like application's version.

Answer (score 1):

The number for the date can be concatenated to the number for the time stuffed with colons. So that it can be converted to a `DATETIME`.

And by using [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) the `DATETIME` can be put in a specific format.
*(But use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) if it has the format.)*

**Test snippet**

> ```
> declare @test table (
>  ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
>  RCLDTE int, 
>  RCLTIM int
> );
>
> insert into @test (RCLDTE, RCLTIM) values
>   (20220119, 215250)
> , (20220304, 070809)
> ;
>
> select 
>   FORMAT(TRY_CAST(CONCAT(c.RCLDTE, ' ', STUFF(STUFF(FORMAT(MAX(c.RCLTIM),'000000'),5,0,':'),3,0,':')) AS DATETIME) 
>   , 'd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') AS [Date & Time] 
> from @test c
> group by RCLDTE;
> ```

> | Date & Time |
> | --- |
> | 19/1/2022 09:52:50 PM |
> | 4/3/2022 07:08:09 AM |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c78bb78b1c7841d674bbf2c347f765a)*

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is very fragile, but I presume your source system gives you few options.

Converting like this has potential problems with DST & the language in use at the time of running.

Your question lost some of the detail regarding formats, so I can't see the time type you are using, but it looks like a decimal again.

Essentially, you need to put the the numerics in a string and then into datetime columns, but to get there you have to match a string conversion format the sqlserver.
Fortunately you are not far off the us format default.

Something like this will get you a date field, you can then amend the output format if you really need 12hr rather than 24hr.

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
DECLARE @rcldte  NUMERIC, @rcltim numeric
SET @rcldte=20220119
SET @rcltim  = 015250 

SELECT  
CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST (@rcldte AS VARCHAR)+ ' ' + 
LEFT( left('000000', 6-LEN(CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR)))+CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR),2) 
+ ':' + substring( left('000000', 6-LEN(CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR)))+CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR),3,2) 
+ ':' + RIGHT( left('000000', 6-LEN(CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR)))+CAST ( @rcltim AS VARCHAR),2))
```

Which will give you:

```
(No column name)
2022-01-19 01:52:50.000
```

It's rather ugly though.
If you can guarantee the hours are zero padded then you could remove the complexity associated with that.
And if you're really going to use it then split into proper UDFs...

Comment: Using `VARCHAR` without a length is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @simon coleman thank you for your reply. I am not sure why but I am still getting the very same result as before... still 2022-01-19 21:52:50.000

Comment: You have to look for the correct last parameter of the CONVERT function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15    `22` seems to deliver `AM/PM`

Comment: @JeroenMostert - agreed - varchar(n) everywhere as per Aaron's blogpost, seemed a bit unecessary for this type of inline. Exercise for the reader...

Comment: @luuk  - check the conversions. At the end the calculation it returns a datetime, not a string. You just see a default string conversion in SSMS. To get the AM/PM, you need to convert to a string with a datetime format parameter - at this point you have a string though, rather than a datetime.

Comment: Sorry, now I see you are converting to DATETIME. I was lost in the question title saying "AM/PM" of which some people say it's not a function that should be handles by the database, but by the tool presenting the data to the user.

Comment: np, and to better assemble, follow jeroen's advice to assemble the sliced string using  DATETIMEFROMPARTS (avoids the language issue I noted)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RCLDTE CHAR(8) = '20220119';
DECLARE @RCLTIM CHAR(6) = '215250';

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(21), (cast(@RCLDTE as DATETIME) + cast(substring(@RCLTIM,1,2)+':'+substring(@RCLTIM,3,2)+':'+substring(@RCLTIM,5,2) as DATEtime) ), 22);
```

output: `01/19/22  9:52:60 PM`

For different formats of the DATETIME, see the docs of the CONVERT function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

NOTE: When specifying another format the value 21 in `VARCHAR(21)` might need a change...

Comment: I think the original is a numeric, so you need to allow for the zero padding on  most hours when converting the date to a char(6)